# Jquery date picker working on firefox but not on chrome and safari

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, webkit, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am implementing a jquery datepicker in my mobile website. It is working totally fine on FF while I can not get it working on chrome. These are the files I included to make the datepicker work.

```
jquery.ui.datepicker.js 
jquery.ui.all.css
jquery.ui.core.css
jquery.ui.datepicker.css
jquery.ui.theme.css
jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js
jquery.mobile.min.js
```

Did I miss any file? Can anyone know why it is not working in safari and chrome? It is not working for any webkit browsers. Thanks in anticipation.

Regards,
BG

Answer (score 0):

Check if You invoke datepicker after page rendering.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".data").datepicker();
});
```

Comment: I did that. I have invoked that. It works on FF. Only chrome has issues.